# Custom CSS buttons

Tags: html, css

**Hi,**

I have some problems with an implementations off custom submit buttons.

pleas take a look on this : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/xhxwS/9/

The submit button is placed on the wrong side of the text input. To fix this I could remove the following :

```
a.btn1 > float: left;
a.btn1 > display: block;
a.btn1 span > display: block;
```

The problem is that the image(button graphics) will look vary strange?

**Pleas advice**

Comment: I don't get it. Edit: I'm guessing I "don't get it" because you're referring to images which don't exist on jsFiddle such as `"Images/Menus/regularButton_span_300x78.png"`, so it doesn't look the same for us.

Comment: Do you want the image on the left, and the input on image's left? or what?

Comment: @thirtydot - Sorry, I didnt know how to upload resources to fiddle but its fixed now.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - The image button is placed to the left but I need it to be placed to the right, this is why I have placed the "button" element after the test input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="" style="width: 100px; float:left;" name="S" id="S" class="tb1" title="Sökord">
<a onclick="" class="btn1">
    <span>Sök</span>
</a>
```

Simply add

> float:left

to the input style and it places on the left, and the image on its right, as you wanted

Comment: But input, <a> and span elements is inline elements, should thay not by default be placed as thay are in code? In this case Input, <a, span, a>? float is often a style I use on div(blocked elements)

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it - put the elements in divs and float the divs

```
<div><div style="float:left"><input type="text" value="" style="width: 100px;" name="S" id="S" class="tb1" title="Sökord"></div>
<div style="float:left"><a onclick="" class="btn1">
    <span>Sök</span>
    </a></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div></div>
```

Comment: Yes I could solve the problem like this but it is alot more code. All the elements I am using in my example is inline elements, should thay not be placed as thay are in code then? float is somthing I use on div(block).